# Next.js & Firebase -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apps')

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

what I am trying to do, is to code an auth. with NextJS and Firebase.

Now the problem appears in my firebaseClient.js, where I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apps')".

The code looks like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
  // config files from firebase here
};

export default function firebaseClient() {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
  }
}
```

In the console I get this error:
[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cczfX.png)

This appears on the localhost:3000:
[Error Page on localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVhLR.png)

I am following this YT tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBGAdenirbs&ab_channel=JamesPerkins) , which is from 2020, so some imports, as far as I can tell, changed.

Comment: This actually helped with the problem, and the error is gone now. However it seems like the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined  (reading 'auth'), is common when working on projects that are maybe outdated.

Comment: It'll be best to checkout for that another issue and ask a new question if still it persists.

Comment: I posted an answer that I found down below. A YouTuber explained the bug and indeed it is because of the different versions. So your link works, but the YouTuber and the tutorial 100% reproduced my bugs/error messages, and following the tutorial the code works now.

Link to video again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkdHUX2Xxvk&ab_channel=DailyWebCoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your code has firebase v8 while you have firebase v9 package and it has completely different import structures. This happen lot when you follow some tutorials with v8 and install firebase so it get latest version on default that's v9

What should you do:

1- Remove current version

`npm rm firebase`

2- install latest of 8.x

`npm install firebase@8.9`

Comment: This helped in a way, that the error was gone, but multiple other errors came up. I think the idea behind your answer, going to the correct version is probably the best.

Comment: I wasted an entire day on this.. Can't believe the version management of firebase!

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial, and the video reproduces 100% of the errors you get with the outdated **v8** firebase version. I followed the tutorial and it actually works, and when adapting the code to firebase **v9**, it runs again.
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkdHUX2Xxvk&ab_channel=DailyWebCoding)

Comment: This answer has several issues. a) Part of it is used instead of a comment on an existing answer, though in this case you can comment on said answer. (You also misused answers for commenting elsewhere, that is why I mention it here.) b) The description of the solution is extremely brief (keep in mind that linked content does not count as an answer on StackOverflow), so this answer is "adapt to firebase v9". c) Your choice of formatting tends to the "noisy", please tone your formatting down a little.